# Why is rails compiling a javascript which is already minified?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Why is rails compiling a javascript which is already minified?

```
Compiled libs/angular-core/angular.min.js  (2731ms)  (pid 19999)
Compiled libs/angular-core/angular-cookies.min.js  (580ms)  (pid 19999)
Compiled libs/angular-core/angular-resource.min.js  (650ms)  (pid 19999)
```

How to tell rails if its already minified it should not be compiled. Is that possible?

Comment: Whats the harm in it?

Comment: @AlexWayne I have a problem with angularjs app when minified I got an error "Error: Unknown provider: tProvider <- t" so one of the suggestion of the community is avoid recompiled a minified angular.min.js. anyway that was not the problem there is an angular scripts I used https://github.com/DerekRies/Angular-Notifications that causes the problem.